# extract data from List<List<T>> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0

```
class FieldType
{
    string Id {get; set;}
    string dataType {get;set;}
}


class Field
{ 
    int fId{get;set;} 
    string fName{get;set;}
    FieldType fType{get;set;}
    string data;
}

class Entity
{
    int eId{get;set;}
    string eName{get;set;}
    List<Field> fields{get;set;}
}
```

```
List<Entity> entities = some entities;
```

Now from the list of entities I want fields' data in a list of string which are having some conditions. such as below but it's giving me List<List<string>>

```
var fields = entities.Select(entity => entity.Fields.Where(field => field.FieldType.Id.Contains(fieldTypeId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.Data as string))
                                                .Select(data => data.Data as string)
                                                .ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: You probably want [`entities.SelectMany(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-7.0) to flatten the lists.

Comment: You have a List<Entity> and every Entity has a List<Field> so that is why you are getting a two dimension array.

Comment: You don't have to cast strings to strings. So `as string` can be left out. You are then converting these strings to lists of strings by including the `.ToList()` after your `data` lambda. Just do `.Select(field => field.data).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

```
var fields = entities
    .SelectMany(e => e.fields)
    .Where(f => f.FieldType.Id.Contains(fieldTypeId)
             && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Data))
    .Select(f => f.Data)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to understand what you are exactly wanting but my guess is that you're trying to extract specific fields' data from a list of entities based on certain conditions, but you're getting a nested list instead of a flat list of strings. To achieve your goal and get a flat List containing the data of fields that meet your conditions, you can use the SelectMany LINQ operator. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
var fieldsData = entities.SelectMany(entity => entity.Fields
                                     .Where(field => field.fType.Id.Contains(fieldTypeId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.data))
                                     .Select(field => field.data))
                         .ToList();
```

This code flattens a list of lists of strings, specifically from the "entities" variable. It processes each "Entity" in the list and their corresponding "Field" objects. The code filters these fields based on specific conditions and extracts the desired field data. Ultimately, it creates a single list containing this extracted data, eliminating any nested lists.

I am not a professional, but here might be one way of adjusting where it would do what you are needing!

Answer (score 0):

I would use following to also get eid and fid

```
            var fields = entities.SelectMany(entity => entity.fields
                                    .Where(field => field.fType.Id.Contains(fieldTypeId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(field.data as string))
                                    .Select(field => new { eid = entity.eId, fid = field.fId, data = field.data} ))
                                 .ToList();
```